# Why do the A220 cockpit seats have a cutout?

Tags: flight-controls, cockpit, feature-identification, seats, airbus-a220

Why do cockpit seats on the A220 have a cutout on the bottom cushion? The answers to [Aircraft pilot's seats: what is the notch for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12439/aircraft-pilots-seats-what-is-the-notch-for) explain that these cutouts allow for easier maneuverability of the yoke. However, this A220 cockpit **has no yoke**. Why does this cockpit have the cutout?

[image]
(source: [thepointsguy.com](https://thepointsguy.com/news/a-look-inside-the-first-airbus-a220-300/))

Comment: Maybe it's to facilitate peeing into a bottle and avoiding the complications of having to go back into the passenger cabin to a lavatory  :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As we have seen in a [previous question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53480/1467), the A220 is a re-branded Bombardier CSeries.

The CSeries started flying in 2013. At the time Bombardier's other commercial jet was the CRJ, that started flying in 1999, 14 years prior.

CRJs do have a yoke:

[image]
([wikimedia.org](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bombardier_CL-600-2E25_Regional_Jet_CRJ-1000_NextGen,_Brit_Air_AN1967464.jpg))

If you look closely, you'll notice that the seats look identical, indicating that Bombardier probably decided to cut on costs by simply re-using something they had already (and minimizing the parts they would have to support).

Moreover, [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12441/1467) mentions the need to have the straps as close to the pilot as possible, and this is achieved with the notch. A redesign of the seats has probably been deemed not worthy of the costs.